# How to wire this fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring

How do you wire this fan?

This is the fan, D2E146-HT65-14 / 455w
The spec sheet of the fan,

[image]

And this is the cord for it.

[image]

As the spec sheet states, the 1 to 4 wires are the speeds, so do I need to have a controller wired into it? Or can I just wire wire number 4 and disregard the rest, as I want the maximum speed?

Comment: Are those speeds, or "steps" on a stepper motor? If the latter, you need controller electronics.

Comment: @keshlam, I am not sure, but the spec sheets states that they are `speeds`.

Answer (score 2):

The research I've just completed indicate that the motor may be called a split phase motor, although there's enough ambiguity in the search results to be uncertain. The indication I've found is that each of the four leads is an independent power lead. A four-position switch, typically rotary, with the common to power and each of the four leads attached to the switch will give you speed control. Prior to purchasing the switch, you can test this by connecting your ground and neutral and making contact with each lead with your 110v source line.

There's no indication of the need for an external controller appropriate to a stepper motor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just connect wire 4 (and neutral and earth/ground). You should do something with the other wires to protect them from shorting out.

Comment: I connected the required wires and plugged it in , but the fan did not work???

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing this in an air handler or furnace, you can simply connect whichever speed leads you're using.  Some fan control modules will have isolated terminals, where you can park the unused leads.  If not, you can simply cap them off.

If you're using the blower in an application where you want to change the speed, you could wire the leads to the terminals of a multi-positional switch.

Comment: I connected the required wires and plugged it in , but the fan did not work???